# How to solve the "update was not wrapped in act()" warning in testing-library-react?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm working with a simple component that does a side effect. My test passes, but I'm getting the warning `Warning: An update to Hello inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).`.

I'm also don't know if `waitForElement` is the best way to write this test.

**My component**

```js
export default function Hello() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
      setPosts(response.data);
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {
          posts.map(
            post => <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>
          )
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**My component test**

```js
import React from 'react';
import {render, cleanup, act } from '@testing-library/react';
import mockAxios from 'axios';
import Hello from '.';

afterEach(cleanup);

it('renders hello correctly', async () => {
  mockAxios.get.mockResolvedValue({
    data: [
        { id: 1, title: 'post one' },
        { id: 2, title: 'post two' },
      ],
  });

  const { asFragment } = await waitForElement(() => render(<Hello />));

  expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Answer (score 115, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

Please refer to @mikaelrs comment below.

> No need for the waitFor or waitForElement. You can just use findBy* selectors which return a promise that can be awaited. e.g await findByTestId('list');

---

**Deprecated answer:**

Use `waitForElement` is a correct way, from the docs:

> Wait until the mocked `get` request promise resolves and the component calls setState and re-renders. `waitForElement` waits until the callback doesn't throw an error

Here is the working example for your case:

`index.jsx`:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Hello() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
      setPosts(response.data);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <ul data-testid="list">
        {posts.map((post) => (
          <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`index.test.jsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render, cleanup, waitForElement } from '@testing-library/react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Hello from '.';

jest.mock('axios');

afterEach(cleanup);

it('renders hello correctly', async () => {
  axios.get.mockResolvedValue({
    data: [
      { id: 1, title: 'post one' },
      { id: 2, title: 'post two' },
    ],
  });
  const { getByTestId, asFragment } = render(<Hello />);

  const listNode = await waitForElement(() => getByTestId('list'));
  expect(listNode.children).toHaveLength(2);
  expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/60115885/index.test.jsx
  ✓ renders hello correctly (49ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.jsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   1 passed, 1 total
Time:        4.98s
```

`index.test.jsx.snapshot`:

```
// Jest Snapshot v1

exports[`renders hello correctly 1`] = `
<DocumentFragment>
  <div>
    <ul
      data-testid="list"
    >
      <li>
        post one
      </li>
      <li>
        post two
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</DocumentFragment>
`;
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/tree/master/stackoverflow/60115885

Comment: btw `waitForElement` is deprecated now. They recommend `import { waitFor } from '@testing-library/react'` . Good answer tho!

Comment: waitFor was needed to mock a property from an html element: `await userEvent.type(r.getByRole('textbox'), 'a'); const fullScreenSection = await waitFor(() => r.getByTestId('FullScreenSection')); fullScreenSection.requestFullscreen = jest.fn(); `

Comment: No need for the `waitFor` or `waitForElement`. You can just use `findBy*` selectors which return a promise that can be awaited. 

e.g
`await findByTestId('list'); ...`

Comment: For me, no alternative worked. It's something so inconsistent that I re run the test 10 times and only 1 time I get the warning, with no change to the code

Comment: What if I don't care about what is displayed after the update and am just asserting if a function that makes a server request is called with the correct data?

Comment: A quick question related to this - according to the documentations (https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#types-of-queries), I assume there is not an async version for `queryBy`? This is because I wanted to verify that an element does not appear in the document and I am currently doing something like this: `await waitFor(() => expect(screen.queryByTestId(testId)).not.toBeInTheDocument());`

Comment: @Elias were you able to answer your own question? What if I don't care what happens after. I don't want to wait for any elements to appear.

Comment: @karlosos nope... I just resorted to awaiting elements I *know* are basically always present...

Comment: What if I'm waiting for `document.title`?

Answer (score 21):

i had a error:

```
console.error
  Warning: A suspended resource finished loading inside a test, but the event was not wrapped in act(...).
  
  When testing, code that resolves suspended data should be wrapped into act(...):
  
  act(() => {
    /* finish loading suspended data */
  });
  /* assert on the output */
  
  This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at https://reactjs.org/link/wrap-tests-with-act
```

code:

```
test('check login link', async () => {
    renderRouter({ initialRoute: [home.path] });
    const loginLink = screen.getByTestId(dataTestIds.loginLink);
    expect(loginLink).toBeInTheDocument();
  
    userEvent.click(loginLink);
    const emailInput = screen.getByTestId(dataTestIds.emailInput);
    expect(emailInput).toBeInTheDocument();
}
```

i have resolved like:

```
test('check login link', async () => {
  renderRouter({ initialRoute: [home.path] });
  const loginLink = screen.getByTestId(dataTestIds.loginLink);
  expect(loginLink).toBeInTheDocument();

  userEvent.click(loginLink);

  await waitFor(() => {
    const emailInput = screen.getByTestId(dataTestIds.emailInput);
    expect(emailInput).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
}
```

i have just wrapped in callback fn - waitFor()

Maybe will be useful for someone

Comment: You don't need to use `waitFor`, you can simply change you `getByTestId` to `findByTestId`. I think it works out to the same thing.

Comment: @lmat-ReinstateMonica you'd still need to await `findByTestId` before expect.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could also show the import statements

Answer (score 15):

`WaitFor` worked for me, I've tried using `findByTestId` as mentioned here, but I still got the same action error.

My solution:

```
it('Should show an error message when pressing “Next” with no email', async () => {
const { getByTestId, getByText  } = render(
  <Layout buttonText={'Common:Actions.Next'} onValidation={() => validationMock}
  />
);

const validationMock: ValidationResults = {
  email: {
    state: ValidationState.ERROR,
    message: 'Email field cannot be empty'
  }
};

await waitFor(() => {
  const nextButton = getByTestId('btn-next');
  fireEvent.press(nextButton);
});

expect(getByText('Email field cannot be empty')).toBeDefined();
```

Answer (score 4):

For me, the solution was to wait for `waitForNextUpdate`

```
it('useMyHook test', async() => {
      const {
        result,
        waitForNextUpdate
      } = renderHook(() =>
        useMyHook(),
      );
      await waitForNextUpdate()
      expect(result.current).toEqual([])
    }
```

Comment: This is a timebomb. If your code changes so that, for instance, another fetch is performed or a `useEffect` triggers another `useEffect` which then updates state, you'll need another `waitForNextUpdate`. In other words, you have to put in enough `waitForNextUpdate` to get through all your promise resolutions which may change in the future! There is a more general solution.

Comment: What is that more general solution?

Comment: waitForNextUpdate is no longer even in the API

Answer (score 4):

slideshowp2's answer above is good but pretty specific to your particular example. (His answer doesn't seem to work because it doesn't wait for the axios promise to resolve; there is always a `list` `testid` present, but that is easily fixed.)

If your code changes so that, for instance, after the `list` `testId` is found, the asserts run, then another `useEffect` is triggered which causes state updates about which you don't care, you'll get the same `act` problem again. A general solution is to wrap the `render` in `act` to make sure all updates are done before proceeding with assertions and the end of the test. Also, those assertions won't need to `waitFor` anything. Rewrite the test body as follows:

```js
axios.get.mockResolvedValue({
  data: [
    { id: 1, title: 'post one' },
    { id: 2, title: 'post two' },
  ],
});
let getByTestId;
let asFragment;
await act(()=>{
  const component = render(<Hello />);
  getByTestId = component.getByTestId;
  asFragment = component.asFragment;
});
const listNode = getByTestId('list');
expect(listNode.children).toHaveLength(2);
expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
```

(Import `act` from the testing library.)

Note that `render` is wrapped in `act`, and finding the list is done using `getBy*` which is not asynchronous! All the promise resolutions are complete before the `getByTestId` call, so no state updates happen after the end of the test.

Comment: What if for example I'm testing the appearance of a loading spinner and don't want to wait for the promise (API call) to be resolved? Then `act(...)` warnings will be visible no matter what. Right?

Comment: There are hacks you can use (`act(<anything with a promise>)` or `await new Promise(process.nextTick)`) which can cause the runtime to go through the promises once more. This will remove the warning, but if you have a promise that spawns another promise, you'll need two "hacks", etc. In general, I have found no way to do that without warnings. Good luck out there!

Comment: or `await act(() => Promise.resolve())` or `await act(async () => '')`

Comment: This worked for me. The first answer isn't enough, with this answer I solve this bug.

Answer (score 0):

A common source of this error in particular is that the code triggering the state changes is not `waiting` for the state changes to happen. Seems obvios, right? but maybe is not that obvious when triggering so many state updates. Let me illustrate my case:

```
// Assert
const user = userEvent.setup();
render(<RouterProvider router={router} />);
// Get a reference to the input elements on the form
const titleField = screen.getByRole("textbox", { name: /title/i });
const descriptionField = screen.getByRole("textbox", {
  name: /description/i,
});
// Get a reference to the submit button
const saveButton = screen.getByRole("button", { name: /Save/i });

// Act
// Fill the inputs 
user.type(titleField, "Go to party");
user.type(descriptionField, "Let's have some fun!");

// Click on save todo
await user.click(saveButton);

// Assert
// expect sentences
```

Everything looks so fine, right? But `.type` is also an async method and it is triggering an state update.
**SOLUTION**

```
// Act
// Fill the inputs (and wait for the state to update)
await user.type(titleField, "Go to party");
await user.type(descriptionField, "Let's have some fun!");

// Click on save todo
await user.click(saveButton);

// Assert
// expect sentences
```