# Using @testing-library/React when is really needed to use the function `act`?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I've written some test that trigger some controlled input and need to wait for a state change.

In this case I supposed to wait for that state change and I tried to use the `act` function to react to that state change but it looks like the same with or without the `act` function.

When is `act` really needed?

Answer (score 1):

[act()](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#act) docs:

> When writing UI tests, tasks like rendering, user events, or data fetching can be considered as “units” of interaction with a user interface. react-dom/test-utils provides a helper called act() that makes sure all updates related to these “units” have been processed and applied to the DOM before you make any assertions

Don't worry, you will know when to use it. You will get a "not wrapped in act(...)" warning like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60115885/how-to-solve-the-update-was-not-wrapped-in-act-warning-in-testing-library-re/60164821#60164821) when you test your component

This is a good post explain when should you need to use it. [use cases for manually calling act(...)](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/fix-the-not-wrapped-in-act-warning#other-use-cases-for-manually-calling-act)

Answer (score 0):

When you perform an action that causes a state update in the component/hook being tested, you should wrap it in the act.

Mostly you can get around this by using `waitFor` on the assertion. This is when wrapping in `act` or not won't make any difference apparently.

The recommended way is to wrap it in `act` and not use waitFor unnecessarily. It will keep your tests quicker and you can avoid making test code asynchronous.