# React Testing Library -- Ignore Unneeded Side-Effects ("Not Wrapped in Act" Warning)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-testing

This minimum working example demonstrates what happens in a smaller test scenario:

`src/code.test.js`:

```
import {useState, useEffect, useCallback} from 'react';
import {render, waitForElementToBeRemoved, fireEvent} from '@testing-library/react';

global.fetch=url=>Promise.resolve({json: ()=>{
    return Promise.resolve('test');
}});

const Component = ({callback}) => {
    const [serverData, setServerData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch('/api/get_it').then(r=>r.json()).then(data=>{
            setServerData(data);
        });
    }, []);

    if (!callback) {
        return <div>No Callback</div>;
    }

    return <div>Server data: {serverData}</div>;
}

test('without callback', async () => {
    const component = render(<Component/>);
    component.getByText('No Callback');
});
```

`package.json`:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "react-scripts test --verbose",
        "check": "jest --version"
    }
}
```

When running this (`npm i && npm test;`), I get

```
Warning: An update to Component inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
...

       7 |
       8 | const Component = ({callback}) => {
    >  9 |     const [serverData, setServerData] = useState(null);
         |                                   ^
      10 |
```

This is because of the `setServerData` call after the `fetch` on line 12 is resolved. In this test case, with the missing `callback`, I don't care about the `serverData`. The naive approach to fixing this would be to add `callback` to the dependency array for the `useEffect` on line 15. That is not acceptable because that `useEffect` should not run again any time `callback` changes!

[How to solve the "update was not wrapped in act()" warning in testing-library-react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60115885/) is materially different from that question because in this question, in my code there is nothing to find.

How can I write this test to avoid this warning?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve the "update was not wrapped in act()" warning in testing-library-react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60115885/how-to-solve-the-update-was-not-wrapped-in-act-warning-in-testing-library-re)

Comment: @W-B The answer to that question says, "You can just use findBy* selectors...", but it's not clear how a "findBy*" selector can help me here. My question is materially different from that question because in this question, there is nothing to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure all state changes are done before proceeding:

```js
let component;
await act(()=>{
    component = render(<Component/>);
});
component.getByText('No Callback');
```

(Import `act` from the testing library.)

Now, no matter how many inner fetches, `useEffect`s or `useEffect`s that trigger other `useEffect`s happen, they (and the state changes they cause) will all be done by the time the `getByText` runs and the test ends.

Comment: This seems fishy, but after fairly extensive testing, it seems to have the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Your `fetch` call runs even if `callback` is undefined which triggers a state change. In most cases you would use `act` and/or `waitFor` to test if your state change has been completed but in this case those are not required because your DOM doesn't change.

A simple fix would be to check if `callback` is defined in the functioned passed to useEffect. You only need to update state if callback is defined.

```js
if(!!callback){ //if callback is defined then fetch
  fetch('/api/get_it').then(r=>r.json()).then(data=>{
    setServerData(data);
  });
}
```

Comment: If I add `if (!callback)`, then I have to add `callback` to the dependency array of the `useEffect`. If I do that, the `useEffect` will run any time `callback` changes which is unacceptable. (I mentioned that in my question: "...should not run again any time `callback` changes!").

Comment: you don't need to add callback to your dependency array and when you specify an empty dependency array, useEffect only runs once.